# Can not even set the bootstrap modal header title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

When I click the CreateTemplate-Button the dialog is shown without backdrop BUT the title has not changed, why?

Even when I remove the h4-tag with the title class there is not title set.

```
  $('#CreateTemplate').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: false, title: "Hello World" });
        });

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="CreateTemplate"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>


   <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thats the title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'title' option supported by the modal method.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage (see the "Options" section)

Answer (score 5):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but there is  a way to change the header title dynamically.

Let's say this is your modal haeder html block:

```
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">&nbsp;</h3>
  </div>
```

Then this is how you would change the modal's title in javascript:

```
 var title = "new title";
 $(".modal-header #myModalLabel").text( title );
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with even bootstrap 2

```js
//apply additional modal settings to modal
$("a[data-toggle='modal']").on('click', function(e) {
 $_clObj = $(this);
 $_mdlObj = $_clObj.attr('data-target');
 $($_mdlObj).on('shown.bs.modal',{ _clObj: $_clObj }, function (event) {
     $_clObj = event.data._clObj;
     if ($_clObj.attr('data-title')!='') //apply modal title from data-title attribute of the clicked element
     $(this).find('.modal-header h3').text($_clObj.attr('data-title')); 
 });
});
```